# cannot SetBackground Resource image for android buttons

Tags: android, background-image, android-button

I want button with two states:

1. OFF
2. ON(or click).

I have set normal image in the button background and I am trying to change image(pressed) from `onClick` method, but it doesn't change.

```
final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

private int flag;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(flag==1)
    {
      button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.on);
          flag=0;
    }
    if(flag==0)
    {
          button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.off);
          flag=1;
    }

}
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is another option: you can use `android.widget.ToggleButton` with selectors:

Code:

```
ToggleButton toggleButton = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
toggleButton.setChecked(true/false);
```

Main layout with snippet:

```
....
<ToggleButton android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textOn=""
              android:textOff=""
              android:background="@drawable/toggle_states"/>
....
```

res/drawable/toggle_states.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/icon_alarm_on"></item>
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/icon_alarm_off"></item>
</selector>
```

Android will set **drawable/icon_alarm_on** or **drawable/icon_alarm_off** automatically depending on state which was set with `ToggleButton.setChecked()` method

Answer (score 4):

```
  if(flag==1)
    {
      button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.on);
          flag=0;
    }
    else if(flag==0)
    {
          button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.off);
          flag=1;
    }
```

you need an `else if` , otherwise when flag = 1, you set the background to `R.drawable.on` and `flag=0;`. The next instruction will be `if (flag == 0)` which is true, and you put again `button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.off);`

Answer (score 3):

Your requirements suits to `ToggleButton` and not just `Button`. you can change your button to Toggle button and `setOnCheckedChangedListener()` for handling on and off states.

Use below code

```
<ToggleButton 
        android:id="@+id/toggle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/check"   //check.xml
        android:textOn=""
        android:textOff=""/>
```

and prepare a drawable xml and store it in drawable folder. name the xml file check.xml

your `check.xml` code should be as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- When selected, use grey -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/your_switched_on_image"
          android:state_checked="true" />
    <!-- When not selected, use white-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawableyour_switched_off_image"
        android:state_checked="false"/>

 </selector>
```

Comment: Lookse like we posted same answer the same time :)

Comment: @virus blackbelt posted first.

Answer (score 2):

you can try with else part

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(flag==1)
    {
      button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.on);
          flag=0;
    }
    else 
    {
          button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.off);
          flag=1;
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The below is more along the lines of what you need but there are some other considerations.

Do you need to remember the state across app restarts/config changes. If so you need to use shared preferences to store the state and retrieve it.

The flag variable, I think, needs to be declared outside the listener or it will be reset every time a click event occurs and you will lose the state. Have a play around with it. Should get you closer:

```
final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
private int flag = 0;

button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(flag==1)
    {
      button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.on);
           flag=0;
    }else if(flag==0)
    {
          button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.off);
          flag=1;
    }

}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

As you are already passing `View` in the function call you may directly use the `view` rather than call `button1`. It is more accurate this way. I used it in my application:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
if(flag==1)
{
      v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.on);
      flag=0;
}
else 
{
      v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.off);
      flag=1;
}
}
```